# How to move part of a file name to a different position

Tags: regex, powershell, file-rename, batch-rename, rename-item-cmdlet

I have a set of files in a folder. I would like to edit all file names by moving part of the file name to a different position. That is a sample of what I have:

```
Par1_MD_0_5_AL_2_ND_4_Dist_0_Pot_Drop_out.txt        
Par1_MD_0_5_AL_2_ND_4_Dist_1_Pot_Drop_out.txt        
Par1_MD_0_5_AL_2_ND_6_Dist_2_Pot_Drop_out.txt        
Par1_MD_0_5_AL_2_ND_8_Dist_3_Pot_Drop_out.txt
```

that is what I want:

```
Par1_MD_0_5_AL_2_Dist_0_ND_4_Pot_Drop_out.txt        
Par1_MD_0_5_AL_2_Dist_1_ND_4_Pot_Drop_out.txt        
Par1_MD_0_5_AL_2_Dist_2_ND_6_Pot_Drop_out.txt        
Par1_MD_0_5_AL_2_Dist_3_ND_8_Pot_Drop_out.txt
```

Basically, I want to place "ND_(number)" after "Dist_(number)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/H1qczt/1) help?

Comment: Use regular expressions like @Mandy8055's suggestion like `$var -replace '(.*?)(ND_\d_)(Dist_\d_)(.*)', '$1$3$2$4'`

Comment: Please do let me know if the answer helped you...or you need something else in regards to this post...

Answer (score 5):

You may try:

```
(.*?)(ND_\d_)(Dist_\d_)(.*)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`(.*?)`** - Represents first capturing group **lazily** matching everything before `ND`.
- **`(ND_\d_)`** - Represents second cpaturing group matching `ND_` followed by a digit. You can alter if digits are more than one like `\d+`.
- **`(Dist_\d_)`** - Represents third capturing group matching `Dist_` literally followed by a digit.
- **`(.*)`** - Represents fourth capturing group matching everything after **greedily**.
- **`$1$3$2$4`** - For the replacement part swap groups `$3` and `$2` to get your required result.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/H1qczt/1/)

**Powershell Command for renaming the files:**

```
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop\Where\Files\Are\Present> Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *.txt | Foreach-Object {
>>   $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ( $_.Name -Replace '(.*?)(ND_\d_)(Dist_\d_)(.*)', '$1$3$2$4' )
>> }
```

**Explanation of the above command:**

```
1. Get-ChildItem - The Get-ChildItem cmdlet gets the items in one or more specified locations
2. -Path . - Represents a flag option for checking in present working directory.
3. -Filter *.txt - Represents another flag option which filters all the .txt files in present working directory.
4. Foreach-Object - Iterate over objects which we got from the above command.
    4.1. Rename-Item -NewName - Rename each item 
         4.2. $_.Name -Replace - Replace the name of each item containing regex pattern with the replacement pattern.
5. end of loop
```